# Como puedo quitar el atributo oculto a un archivo en java?

Tags: java

```
package com.resolvethis.nio;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MakeFileHidden {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\ITSAO\\Documents\\testfile.txt");
            Boolean hidden = (Boolean) Files.getAttribute(path, "dos:hidden" , LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);

                         if (hidden != null && !hidden){
                         Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden" , Boolean.TRUE, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
                               System.out.println("File is now hidden!");   
        }
    }catch (IOException ex){
           System.err.println("Things went wrong: " + ex.getMessage());
           ex.printStackTrace();  

               }
           } 
      }
```

//Ocupe este bloque de codigo para ocultar el archivo que yo quiera elegir pero quiero saber que metodo o de que forma lo puedo volver a hacer visible?

Answer (score 1):

Para quitar la propiedad "hidden" simplemente define la propiedad con valor "False":

```
Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden" , Boolean.FALSE, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
```

puedes agregar este bloque de código:

```
 if (hidden != null && hidden){
         Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden" , Boolean.FALSE, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
         System.out.println("File is now visible!");           
     }
```

de esta forma tu archivo dejaría de tener la propiedad hidden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información me sirvió de mucho :D

Comment: @YhairRamos Si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada pulsando en el icono que tiene en la parte superior izquierda.